# Cannot find AddHealthChecks().AddUrlGroup() not found on .NET Core 2.2

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am trying to health check an endpoint in .NET Core using `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks`. Most of the samples code i found is like below

> ```
> services.AddHealthChecks()
>             .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("** API 1 ENDPOINT **"), "API 1");
> ```

But i am getting reference error for same telling 
`IHealthChecksBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddUrlGroup' and no accessible extension method 'AddUrlGroup' accepting a first argument of type 'IHealthChecksBuilder' could be found`

Is there any other reference for `AddUrlGroup` or it is not available in .net core 2.2?

Comment: Install this package `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install below NuGet Package will solve your issue

AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris

> Install-Package AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris -v 2.2

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris/